# Windows Phone 8.1 RT view not updating (MVVM)

Tags: xaml, mvvm, windows-phone-8.1

I'm designing a profile page for users where they can edit their personal info. I'm using a PersonViewModel (which contains the current signed in person) to display the current info about the User. The fields to edit the user's info are bound to a validation model. After pressing the 'execute changes' button and I get a response of the server (HTTPStatusCode Ok + the altered user object), I alter the fields of the existing object according to the changes. Then I used setter injection to update my PersonViewModel... When debugging, I can see that my objects are all up-to-date but my view is still displaying the old info... What am I doing wrong?`

This is the code that get's executed when I press the button to execute my changes:

```
    private async void ChangeInfoButton(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        User user;
        List<ErrorInfo> errors;
        if (_profileInformationValidationModel.TryGetUser(out user, out errors))
        {
            var response = await Session.Instance.DataProvider.UpdaterUserInfo(user);

            if (response.IsSuccess)
            {
                /*SignedInUserInfo = AlteredUserInfo*/
                Session.Instance.User.Information = user.Information;  
                _personViewModel.SetPerson(user.Information);
                var d1 = new MessageDialog("Uw gegevens werden succesvol gewijzigd.");
                d1.ShowAsync();

                AnnulInfoButton(sender, e);
            }
```

`
And this is the PersonViewModel:

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
    private Person _person;

    public void SetPerson(Person p)
    {
        _person = p;
    }

    public PersonViewModel(Person person)
    {
        _person = person;
    }

    public string Street
    {
        get { return _person.Street; }
    }

    public string HouseNumber
    {
        get { return _person.HouseNumber; }
    }

    public string Bus
    {
        get { return _person.Bus; }
    }

    public string Email
    {
        get { return _person.Email; }
    }
```

Comment: Your mvvm pattern is incorrect.  There is really little difference between your model and your model.  Post your xaml binding.

Answer (score 0):

Your view model should implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) interface.

Look into using a framework like [MVVM Light](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) which does most of this work for you.

You can add it to your project using [NuGet](http://nuget.codeplex.com/).

This is how your model and view-model should look:

```
public class Person
{

    public string Street { get; set; }

    public string HouseNumber { get; set; }

    public string Bus { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class PersonViewModel : System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Person _person;

    public void SetPerson(Person person)
    {
        _person = person;
        Street = person.Street;
        HouseNumber = person.HouseNumber;
        Bus = person.Bus;
        Email = person.Email;
    }

    public PersonViewModel(Person person)
    {
        SetPerson(person);
    }

    #region Street (INotifyPropertyChanged Property)
    private string _street;

    public string Street
    {
        get { return _street; }
        set
        {
            if (_street != value)
            {
                _street = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Street");
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion


    #region HouseNumber (INotifyPropertyChanged Property)
    private string _houseNumber;

    public string HouseNumber
    {
        get { return _houseNumber; }
        set
        {
            if (_houseNumber != value)
            {
                _houseNumber = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("HouseNumber");
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Bus (INotifyPropertyChanged Property)
    private string _bus;

    public string Bus
    {
        get { return _bus; }
        set
        {
            if (_bus != value)
            {
                _bus = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Bus");
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion


    #region Email (INotifyPropertyChanged Property)
    private string _email;

    public string Email
    {
        get { return _email; }
        set
        {
            if (_email != value)
            {
                _email = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Email");
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion


    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string p)
    {
        var propertyChanged = PropertyChanged;
        if (propertyChanged != null)
        {
            propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(p));
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: My person object already implements this interface. Just to be sure I implemented the viewmodel as well but it didn't make a difference. Are you sure I've implemented my viewmodel correctly?

Comment: Your view model should implement it, not your model. Also the properties in it should raise the PropertyChanged event.

Comment: I've already changed it and it doesn't make any difference. I tried to use setter injection to update the user object and this didn't work out either. Other ideas?

Comment: I tested with the code I posted and it worked for me, so I need more context about your problem to reproduce it.